# flatpickr, link two input fields to get a period

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, flatpickr

I am trying to implement flatpickr with Jquery. So far so good.

I have the following code, which actually works :

```
flatpickr("#booking_start", {});
flatpickr("#booking_end", {});
```

However I would like to change this code into a period.
I have tried to figure out how to do this with the [flatpickr reference page](https://flatpickr.js.org/options/) :

But as soon as I add the code `"onChange"`, I basically get an error. I know I am very likely making a syntax error, but I simply getting stuck at this point.

```
flatpickr("#booking_start", { onchange({ alert('hi there') }) });
flatpickr("#booking_end", {});
```

In the end I want to turn this into a period selector. Hence when you click start date, the start date should automatically set the minimum date for the end date.

But for now I am actually not getting any further.

*Edit:*

*Seb Cesbron gave me the correct answer!*

```
startPicker = flatpickr("#booking_start", {
  onChange: function(selectedDates, dateStr, instance) {
    endPicker.set('minDate', selectedDates[0]);
  }
});
endPicker = flatpickr("#booking_end", {});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the right syntax

```
startPicker = flatpickr("#booking_start", {
  onChange: function(selectedDates, dateStr, instance) {
    endPicker.set('minDate', selectedDates[0]);
  }
};
endPicker = flatpickr("#booking_end", {});
```